# error C:\...\.sbt\0.13\plugins\idea.sbt:1: illegal character '\u0000

Tags: intellij-idea

I updated my `IntelliJ` and am not getting the followingn error when I try to build my project. I am using `IntelliJ 2018.3.1 Ultimate Edition`

`error] [C:\Users\TestUser\.sbt\0.13\plugins\idea.sbt]:1: illegal character '\u0000`

Comment: why was my question marked down?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the `.sbt` folder, then I deleted the `.idea` folder and also removed previous version of `SBT` and reinstalled `SBT`. I re-imported the project into `IntelliJ` and the build started working again